# Mongodb crash . intermittent issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crash

I have a 8 core cpu with 32 gb ram running 50 node processes . Mongo db crashes once everyday and this is an intermittent issue . Any idea what might be causing this or how debugging can be approached .

Comment: This question might be more suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead of StackOverflow. When posting your question, please include relevant details, e.g. logs, the MongoDB setting, what are the 50 nodes processes and why are they running in the same server as MongoDB, etc.

Comment: sorry my bad . Thanks for the suggestion